# Function highlighting with monokai in VS Code / Atom and Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, visual-studio-code

While running Sublime Text 3 and VS Code (or Atom) with the Monokai color theme, the Sublime Text syntax highlighting uses blue for function calls, such as in the example below

[image: Sublime Text function highlighting]

However, when I open the same code in VS Code using the monokai theme, functions are not painted blue

[image: VS Code function highlighting]

I would really like to change that, the code looks much better with function calls highlighted. However, I looked around the web and couldn't find how to change this behavior. Does anyone have any tips for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the exact same `.tmTheme` files or different version of the Monokai theme? There are countless versions of Monokai, yet some might be less faithful than others. However, syntax grammar also has influence on how code is colored.

Comment: have the same error, and don't find the fix

Comment: I think answer for your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405209/javascript-color-highlighting-error-in-vscod)

Answer (score 2):

### SEE UPDATE BELOW!

---

Seems like I've found a temporary solution. Go to this folder (if you are on Mac) */Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/theme-monokai/themes* and put this code in monokai-color-theme.json file:

```json
{
    "name": "Function call",
    "scope": "meta.function-call.generic",
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#66d9efff"
    }
},
```

Here is an example how it can look like:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfGd2.png)

But keep in mind, that after theme update this changes may disappear!

**UPDATE:**
After having a couple more troubles with highlighting, I decided to upload the file with theme to GitHub and keep it up to date.  So, if you don't want to dive into the code, just look in my repository: https://github.com/spyker77/monokai-theme-extended

---

#### UPDATE (April 2021)

It turns out that the previous solution is not sustainable. Therefore at the moment a better one could be:

1. In you Visual Studio Code go to "Code" => "Preferences" => "Color Theme" and pick **Monokai**;
2. Open `settings.json` file ([how-to](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_tune-your-settings));
3. There will probably already be a bunch of settings in there, so all you need to do is just add the following customisations at the end and before the closing brace (don't forget a trailing comma after the last setting you continue):

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Monokai]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "name": "Decorator definition decorator",
                    "scope": "punctuation.definition.decorator.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#F92672"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Meta function-call",
                    "scope": "meta.function-call.generic.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#66D9EF"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Storage type function async",
                    "scope": "storage.type.function.async.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#F92672",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Punctuation separator period",
                    "scope": "punctuation.separator.period.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#F8F8F2",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Entity name function decorator",
                    "scope": "entity.name.function.decorator.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#66D9EF",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Entity name type class",
                    "scope": "entity.name.type.class.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "fontStyle": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Entity other inherited-class",
                    "scope": "entity.other.inherited-class.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "fontStyle": "italic"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Support type python",
                    "scope": "support.type.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "fontStyle": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "String quoted docstring multi python",
                    "scope": "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#88846F",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings.json:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Monokai]": {
    {
      "scope": "entity.name.function",
      "settings": {
      "foreground": "#fdc306d0",  // use your desired color
      "fontStyle": "underline"    // I like this, foreground color has some reduced opacity
     }
   }
 }
}
```

might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

after trying for server hours finally found a solution and I came back to you to share the solution since I tried the answer above and couldn't make it work.
it turns out that the problem I with VScode extensions (python for Vscode), so disable that first,[extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpFvY.png)

then go to your `setting.json` file like that [how to open setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZseVA.png)

add this to the top of your file

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "meta.function-call.generic",
            "settings": {
                "foreground":"#19D1E5"
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

and restart VScode and this should work, btw I am using monokai vibrent, and I am sure it will work in any theme you like.
[setting.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr7PA.png)

like this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cboep.png)