# JavaScript color highlighting error in VScode

Tags: javascript, themes, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have fresh install of VScode editor (v.1.14.2). Doesn't have any installed extensions. I have problem with javaScript highlighting in very simple file.
[image: js code in default VScode]

The same code in Sublime Text 3:

[image: js code in default ST3]

Default VScode theme (Dark+), doesn't have this bug, and all function names and methods have the same colors. But many another themes (monokai and Abyss for example) have this bug/feature.

I want to have for function names and methods the same color (line 10, 11, 13, 16). Ideally, all lines like in ST3 - blue (line 13 - green). But, it's ok if it would be a green.

I read [scope naming](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html) link, try to compare different themes. Install all monokai-based themes, but all of theme, has this bug. I tried to create new one, but I didn't do what I need.

So, does it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use vscode command `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` for scope inspection. This color changes because vscode thinks `click()`, `addEventListener()`... is special DOM-related properties and should be highlighted.

Workaround would be modifying `monokai-color-theme.json` in

`Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-monokai\themes`.

In this array `"tokenColors": []` add:

```
{
    "name": "DOM & invocation color fix",
        "scope": "meta.function-call.js entity.name.function, meta.function-call.js support.function.dom.js",
            "settings": {
        "foreground": "#66D9EF"
    }
}
```

This will make function calls & DOM-methods sublime-like.

P.S. If theme updates it will most likely overwrite this file.

#### Edit:

From some version it is possible to modify theme from [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": ["meta.function-call.js entity.name.function", 
                "meta.function-call.js support.function.dom.js"],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#66D9EF"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much. I understand about file, disable overwrite or make my own theme "with cards and girls"

Answer (score 1):

Your function should not have an end-line ";" added. Your variable test however should have one, this is simple syntax error and doesn't always get caught. This post is years late but it came up in search and the above suggestion is too much work.